# Parsing CSV from stream with TextFieldParser always reaches EndOfData

Tags: vb.net, csv, stream, blob, textfieldparser

During parsing CSV file as a stream from Azure Blob, TextFieldParser always reaches EndOfData immediately, without any data read. The same code, but with the path to same physical file instead of stream works.

```
    Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AzureStorageConnection)
    Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
    Dim BlobList As IEnumerable(Of CloudBlockBlob) = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername").ListBlobs().OfType(Of CloudBlockBlob)

    For Each blb In BlobList
        Dim myList As New List(Of MyBusinessObject)

        Using memoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            blb.DownloadToStream(memoryStream)

            Using Reader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(memoryStream)
                Reader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
                Reader.SetFieldWidths(2, 9, 10)
                Dim currentRow As String()
                While Not Reader.EndOfData
                    Try
                        currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
                        myList.Add(New GsmXFileRow() With {
                        ' code to read currentRow and add elements to myList
                        })
                    Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    End Try
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
```

I have also tried to convert `MemoryStream` to `TextReader`

```
Dim myTextReader As TextReader = New StreamReader(memoryStream)
```

and then passing `myTextReader` into `TextFieldParser`, but this does not work either.

`Using Reader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(myTextReader)`

Comment: Have you put in a breakpoint and checked that your `memoryStream` has the data you expect? Also... I see your Try/Catch block is swallowing the caught exceptions. Have you run the code without Try/Catch, to see if any errors are thrown? I suspect an encoding issue converting the bytes to strings is resulting in MalformedLineExceptions you never see.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes. Value of `Length` property equals file size. 'Position` property has same value what suggest stream is positioned at its end. On exceptions, code never executes within `While` as `Reader.EndOfData` is always `True`.

Comment: "`Position property has same value`". There's your problem, then. It's already read to the end of the steam. You need to put yourself back at the beginning. And when you do that, check my answer, because you may need to address the encoding issue as well.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Sorry, didn't understand how to solve this. `TextFieldParser` accepts only `Stream` or `TextReader`. How to convert blob into one of those?

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this:

> Value of Length property equals file size

and this:

> 'Position` property has same value

That means at the start of the loop, the `MemoryStream` has already advanced to the end of the stream. Just set `Position` back to 0, and you should be in a better place.

However, there may be another issue here, too. That stream data is binary with some unknown encoding. The `TextFieldParser` wants to work with `Text`. You need a way to give the `TextFieldParser` information about what encoding is used.

In this case, I recommend a `StreamReader`. This type inherits from `TextReader`, so you can use it with the `TextFieldParser` :

```
Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AzureStorageConnection)
Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
Dim BlobList As IEnumerable(Of CloudBlockBlob) = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername").ListBlobs().OfType(Of CloudBlockBlob)

Dim myList As New List(Of MyBusinessObject)
For Each blb In BlobList

    'Several constructor overloads allow you to specify the encoding here
    Using blobData As New StreamReader(New MemoryStream())
        blb.DownloadToStream(blobData.Stream)

        'Fix the position problem
        blobData.Stream.Position = 0

        Using Reader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(blogData)
            Reader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
            Reader.SetFieldWidths(2, 9, 10)
            Dim currentRow As String() = Reader.ReadFields()
            While Not Reader.EndOfData
                Try
                    myList.Add(New GsmXFileRow() With {
                        ' code to read currentRow and add elements to myList
                    })
                    currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
                Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
                End Try
            End While
        End Using 
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: `Using rdr As New StreamReader(rdr)`  ??? I think you left in a partial train of thought in your example.  Also the `TextFieldParser` can be configured with a default encoder as well as to try and detect encoding.

Comment: @TnTinMn  Sorry... you caught me between edits. Look again.

Comment: I think you would be better off filling the `MemoryStream` before passing it to the `StreamReader` as the SR's constructor chain does a detect encoding on the stream; if it is empty there may be a issue.  But then, I do not understand the need for the `StreamReader` in the first place as the `TextFieldParser` can accept a `Stream` and optional encoding to construct its own internal `StreamReader`,

Comment: Now Works faster. One more comment - `blobData.Stream` shall be `blobData.BaseStream`